# apply object of style to DOM element

Tags: javascript, css

I know we can use `.style` to apply css to DOM element like this:

`document.getElementById("test").style.color="red";`

I am wondering, if it is possible to apply a style object, something like this:

```
newStyle: {
  position : 'fixed';
  width : '300px';
  height : '20px';
  top : '0';
}
```

how to apply `newStyle` by using `.style`, is it possible? ( We are not using jQuery here)

Comment: That is an invalid object. Interchange the `:` and `=`.

Comment: You should not try and overwrite the `style` property with a JS object. Instead, loop through your object (`for in` loop), and assign each value to the style property individually.

Comment: You could do that, but you could also just add, or remove, a class-name and use CSS; which would be easier, and far more maintainable.

Comment: @DavidThomas That's a preferred way, but sometimes it is not possible when the properties to be applied are calculated dynamically using JS

Comment: If you're considering using jQuery, you can do that easily using `$('selector').css(object);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```js
Object.assign(myElement.style, {
  width: '300px',
  height: '20px'
});
```

```js
Object.assign(document.getElementById("test").style, {
  position: 'fixed',
  width: '300px',
  height: '100px',
  top: '0'
});
```

```html
<div id="test" style="background: green"></div>
```

Comment: Interesting, but the snippet doesn't work, throwing undefined error

Comment: @Tushar Use Firefox, then.

Comment: @Xufox I'm using latest Safari so I expect it to work. Oriol, if this doesn't support all browser then please add it's [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Polyfill) also.

Comment: @Tushar I already linked the MDN page with the polyfill. `Object.assign` has been supported on Firefox since 10 versions ago, so I no longer warn it's something new.

Comment: it works for me in chrome for Android. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
var mystyle = {
  color: 'red'
};
for (var property in mystyle) {
  if (mystyle.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
    document.getElementById("updateStyle").style[property] = mystyle[property];
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="updateStyle">Hi This is demo text.</p>
```

replace `updateStyle`with your own id

Comment: thank you, but I think Oriol's answer fit me better!

Answer (score 1):

Applying rule by rule is bad. It makes the browser re-render multiple times. You can apply all the changes in one shot - by using [cssText](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_csstext.asp)

So, in your case, you need to convert the object into a string and then apply all the styles in one shot:

```
var newStyle = {
  position: 'fixed',
  width: '300px',
  height: '20px',
  top: '0'
}

var styles = [];
for(var rule in newStyle) styles.push(rule+': '+newStyle[rule]);

document.getElementById("test").style.cssText = styles.join(';');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can loop through properties of styles as -

```
  var newStyle = {
  position : 'fixed',
  width : '300px',
  height : '20px',
  top : '0'
};

for (i in newStyle)
  document.getElementById("test").style[i] = newStyle[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the prototype of the "[HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement)". Add a method to loop through a object containing the style information. You can do it like this:

```
HTMLElement.prototype.applyStyleObject = function (styleObject) {
  for (var item in this.style) {

    var objProp = styleObject[item];

    if (objProp !== undefined) {
      this.style[item] = objProp;
    }

  }
}
```

I've done a first prototype as an example how to use this in the wild :):

```js
//The object containing the style elements

var obj = {
  width: "200px",
  height: "100px"
}

var spanobj = {
  color: "red"
}

//Cached the div node

var divNode = document.getElementById("div");

//Extend the HTMLElement prototype

HTMLElement.prototype.applyStyleObject = function (styleObject) {
  for (var item in this.style) {
  
    var objProp = styleObject[item];
  
    if (objProp !== undefined) {
      this.style[item] = objProp;
    }
  
  }
}

//Execute the new method

divNode.applyStyleObject(obj);
document.getElementById("span").applyStyleObject(spanobj);
document.getElementsByTagName("figure")[0].applyStyleObject(obj);
```

```css
div {
  border: solid 1px black;
}

figure {
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
<span id="span">This is a span tag</span>
<figure></figure>
```

If you've extended the [prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype) of an javascript object, it applies to all newly created instances of that kind of object.

Comment: thank you, but I think Oriol's answer fit me better!

Comment: @JavaScripter Glad to help. Be aware that his answer isn't supported everywhere.

Comment: oh, I am in a React project and I used babel with ES6, it should work fine.